# Can creat function return zero and what's the meaning of it?

Tags: c, linux

I'm currently working with a legacy code in Linux and encounter with a piece of code that uses `creat` function in `fcntl.h` header for creating a new file or rewriting an existing one. This code assumed return value below zero as an error and above zero as a valid file descriptor and didn't consider zero.

Is zero a valid file descriptor and indicating a successful function call or not? [Documentations](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/creat.html) say:

> Upon successful completion, the function shall open the file and return a non-negative integer representing the lowest numbered unused file descriptor.  Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error.

Comment: "Non-negative" includes 0, so that's valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, zero is a valid file descriptor. It is typically stdin, but if you first `close(0)` and then call `creat(...)`, the kernel will reuse file descriptor number 0 for the created file.

If the code you're looking at doesn't consider this, it might be a bug. Even if your executable never closes fd 0 itself, it would would fail in an environment where file descriptor 0 has already been closed before your code started to run. In the bash shell, you can trigger this with `./myprogram 0<&-`.